# Find monday of after a certain date

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 tables, Table 1 and Table 2. Both the tables have one date column each. I am inserting the first Monday of the month on top of the table 1 and Table 2, both. I will fetch date value from each row of the table 2, and if it is more than the value on top of the table, I will insert 0. If the date value in the table 2 is "16/02/2018", and it is not a Monday, I will insert the Monday after it, and the value 1 for that record.How can I proceed with it? Please help.

[image]

```
    Dim col_tab2_dat as Date 
    first_day = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1)
    last_day = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 1)
    curr_month= Format(first_day, "mmm")

    w = Weekday(first_day , vbMonday)
    FirstMonday = first_day + IIf(w <> 1, 8 - w, 0)
    tab1_last_lin = ws.Columns(2).Find("Total(T1)").Row
    tab2_last_lin = ws.Columns(2).Find("Total(T2)").Row
    find_tab2 = ws.Columns(1).Find("Table 2").Row
    last_lin = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    last_col_tab1 = ws.Cells(tab1_last_lin, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    last_col_tab2 = ws.Cells(tab2_last_lin, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    last_dat = ws.Cells(2, last_col_tab1  - 1).Value
    new_date = last_dat + 7
         For i =  find_tab2 + 3 to  tab2_last_lin 
            ws.Cells(find_tab2 + 3, 1).Value = col_tab2_dat
            If col_tab2_dat > last_dat Then
```

I am stuck here. What to do next?

```
            End If
         Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will return the next Monday:

```
Public Function GetNextMonday(dt As Date) As Date
  Do Until Weekday(dt, vbSunday) = 2
    dt = DateAdd("d", 1, dt)
  Loop
  GetNextMonday = dt
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will work for any day of the week.

## NextWeekday Function:

```
Function NextWeekday(FromDate As Date, vbWeekday As VbDayOfWeek) As Date

    If Weekday(FromDate) < vbWeekday Then
        NextWeekday = FromDate + vbWeekday - Weekday(FromDate)
    Else
        NextWeekday = FromDate + 7 + vbWeekday - Weekday(FromDate)
    End If
    
End Function
```

**It takes two arguments:**

> - `FromDate`: The Date of which you are wanting to find the next weekday of. You can simply use "Date" as the argument for today's Date.
> - `vbWeekday`: The upcoming day of the week you are wanting the date for.

## VBA Example:

Once you've added the above function to your code module, it's easy to get its value:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim NextThursday As Date
    NextThursday = NextWeekday(Date, vbThursday)

End Sub
```

## Worksheet Formula Example:

Or you can use it as a worksheet function:

```
=NextWeekday(Today(), 5)
```

#### Worksheet Formula Considerations:

> Notice in the worksheet formula we had to remove the `vbThursday` constant as worksheet functions doesn't have this functionality *built-in*. However, if you want to still use these constant values in your worksheet, you can ***create them yourself by using the Name Manager***.
>
> - Click on the **Formulas Tab**, then on **Define Name**
>   [image]
> - Start creating your constants starting at `vbSunday = 1` through `vbSaturday = 7` by placing the Constant Name in the **Name:** field, and the value in the **Refers to:** field:
>   [image]
>
> And there you have it! You can now refer to them using your named values:
> [image]

## Additional Example Usage:

> [image]

## Comments:

The benefit of using the `VbDayOfWeek` Type is that you will now gain IntelliSense when using the function:

> [image]